# Configure Windows Smartscreen GPO is Missing Options

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I run three AD servers, and I'm trying to implement the same policy on all three:

**Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer\Configure Windows SmartScreen**

On one of the servers, the policy correctly displays the Options:

[image]

But on the other two, the options do not display and therefore cannot be set:

[image]

I have downloaded the most recent ADMX files and installed them in the Central Store for the servers where the options are missing, but the problem persists. Two of my servers are 2012R2, and one is 2016, but the one that correctly displays the Options is one of the 2012R2 servers, so the operating system version doesn't seem like it could be the cause.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Check the IE version installed, as it's a IE policy, it make a difference

Comment: Looks like they are both 11.0.38.

Comment: It does appear to just be a difference in the XML. The policy that doesn't display the options is missing an <elements> declaration that contains the options values. Anyone know if it's a problem to just add those in manually?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. You're trying to edit a domain based GPO on all three servers or you're trying to apply a domain based GPO to all three servers?

Comment: I'm trying to edit the GPO. The three servers are totally separate from each other, so I have three separate objects, and I'm trying to make the same changes to each object.

Comment: For the record, the ADMX totally breaks if I edit the XML manually. I wonder if the options are just deprecated now, but the Help text just hasn't been updated to reflect the change. I noticed elsewhere (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80b7e5b3-1a13-4ae0-90ce-35996bdbc0ff/missing-options-gpo-server-2016-admx-templates-for-enablesmartscreen?forum=winserverGP) that one of the options had been removed in an earlier update to the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the server that has the options is using older ADMX files. The new ones have the options removed. I suspect Microsoft is deprecating the "Options" part of this policy but just hasn't updated the Help text to reflect the change. They had already removed one of the Options, so maybe they have just decided Options are no longer necessary. I couldn't find any confirmation of this elsewhere, though.

Regardless of the reason, if I roll the WindowsExplorer.admx back to a previous version, the Options reappear.